# Node.js and multiple queries without blocking event loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

Consider a situation where 5000 users are there in the mongodb and in one shot for each user 
we need to do some computation which will  query from n number of collections. We will do this everyday at a particular time. How this can be achieved this without blocking the event loop?

Answer (score 0):

try spawm or fork to create  a child process to get what you need done and get the results

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

also watch this as a guide on how to use it

[How to use parallel child processes to perform "work" on a large array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376416/how-to-use-parallel-child-processes-to-perform-work-on-a-large-array)